# Unhandled exception at 0x00D64674

Tags: c++

```
#include "Cell.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Cell::CreateArea(int x[][100], int y[][100], int f, int c, int tc){
int f1, c1;
for (int i = -1; i <= f; i++){
    for (int j = -1; j <= c; j++){
        x[i][j] = 0;
        y[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
//Copy(y,x,f,c); //copy the matrix of zeros in another temporary array
while (tc){
    bool re = true;
    while (re){
        f1 = rand() % f;
        c1 = rand() % f;
        if (x[f1][c1] == 0)
        {
            x[f1][c1] = 1; //enter random cells in random positions that are not repeated
            re = false;
        }
    }
    tc--; //decreases the umber of cells to be entered
  }
}

void Cell::PrintArea(int x[][100], int f, int c){
for (int i = 0; i<f; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<c; j++){
        if (x[i][j] == 1) cout << '*'; //Prints a "*" if cells are alive 
        else cout << '.'; //Prints a "." if cells are dead 
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

int Cell::Population(int x[][100], int f, int c){
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<f; i++)
for (int j = 0; j<c; j++)
if (x[i][j] == 1)counter++;
return counter;
```

}

when i run this code it works but after it excutes it crashes giving me the error:
Unhandled exception at 0x00D64674 in C++AssignmentPart1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFE88.

Does anybody know why please? U have been at this for hours!

Comment: "U have been at this for hours! " - really - only just seen the question :-) But why not use the debugger?

Comment: Build a debug version, and run in a debugger. It will tell you *where* the crash happens, and let you examine and walk up the function call stack as well as examine values of variables.

Comment: Also why not use vectors

Comment: My guess? You're writing out of bounds of the arrays. For once, you are writing to *negative* indexes. Also, in some cases you use e.g. `i < f` and other `i <= f` as loop condition, which seems suspect to me.

Comment: An array of length `n` in C/C++ is *legally* indexed from `0...(n-1)`. Period. Use that bit of info to fix your code and make sure that rule is *never* violated.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are going from `0` to `n-1`, so `CreateArea` loops are incorrect:

```
for (int i = -1; i <= f; i++){
    for (int j = -1; j <= c; j++){
```

-1 is not a valid array index! You must go from 0 to f or c. Most likely excluding f and c if they are zero-based (that's what people often do as indexes of your array are from 0 to 99):

```
for (int i = 0; i < f; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < c; j++){
```

Also check that f and c are lower than 100 at the beginning of the function! Then, you'll be sure you never write outside array bounds...

Comment: Why in the world would he put a `-1` in there?

Comment: Thank you so much both of you! thanks you made my year. First post that actually helped me

Comment: Good. Then, please vote up and mark as correct answer ;-)